# Is the set of non-decreasing bounded continuous functions a compact set with the norm $(,)=\sup|−|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

$\Phi$ is the set of functions $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is bounded, non-decreasing
and continuous on $[a, b]$. Is $\Phi$ compact with the norm $(,)=\sup|−|$?

Answer (score 3):

Your set is unbounded and thus not compact (consider $f_n(x)=nx$).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the space such that the range of the function is bounded and it allows the function to be discontinuous. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770372/is-the-set-of-non-decreasing-bounded-functions-a-compact-set-with-the-norm