# Is the set of uniformly bounded non-decreasing functions a compact set with the metric $(,)=\sup|−|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Fix $M>0$. Let $\Phi = \{f|f:[a, b] \to [-M, M] \, \text{is an non-decreasing function} \}$. Define a metric $d: \Phi \times \Phi \to [0, \infty)$ by $(,)=\sup_{x \in [a, b]}|(x)−(x)|$. Is the topology induced by  compact?

Comment: so it's non-decreasing and uniformly bounded

Comment: @alphaomega Yes, I reedited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ftor If you fix a global bound $N$ at the very beginning, $\Phi$ is not a vector space because it cannot be closed under scalar multiplication. Then, it is not appropriate to use the word "norm" because it is for a vector space.

Comment: @ftor Or, does $N$ depend on $f$ ?

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thanks. I reedited the question but I am not sure if this is right way to write. Actually, I want to find a function space (that is decreasing functions) that is compact under some metric. I know that bounded or continuous will not work.

Comment: @flor You should write: Fix $M>0$. Let $\Phi=\{f\mid f:[a,b]\rightarrow[-M,M]\mbox{ is an increasing function.\}}.$
Define a metric $d:\Phi\times\Phi\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$.
Is the topology induced by $d$ compact?

Comment: Do you really wish to include $\pm\infty$ to the codomain of $f$'s? Those values essentially spoil the idea of 'uniform boundedness'.

Comment: Sorry. I reedited the question.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO. Counter-example: Consider the case that $M=10$,
$a=0$, $b=1$. Recall that for a metric space, the metric topology
is compact iff it is sequentially compact (i.e., Every sequence has
a convergent subsequence). Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary
that $(\Phi,d)$ is compact. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}:[0,1]\rightarrow[-10,10]$
by $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}$. Clearly $f_{n}$ is increasing, so $f_{n}\in\Phi$.
Consider the sequence $(f_{n})$. By the compactness assumption, there
exists $f\in\Phi$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ such that $d(f_{n_{k}},f)\rightarrow0$
as $k\rightarrow\infty$. In particular, for each $x\in[0,1]$, $|f_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow0$
as $k\rightarrow\infty$. It follows that
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }x\in[0,1)\\
1, & \mbox{ if }x=1
\end{cases}.
$$
Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{100}$. Then there exists $K\in\mathbb{K}$
such that $d(f_{n_{k}},f)<\varepsilon$ whenenver $k\geq K$. Hence,
for any $x\in[0,1)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |x^{n_{K}}|\\
 & = & |f_{n_{K}}(x)-f(x)|\\
 & \leq & d(f_{n_{K}},f)\\
 & < & \frac{1}{100}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Letting $x\rightarrow1-$ and observing that $x^{n_{K}}\rightarrow1$,
we have $1<\frac{1}{100}$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

As written, no, since the set is unbounded.

Comment: I reedit the question. Actually this is what I originally want to ask. Your answer is helpful.

Comment: @ftor What have you tried? It’s also bad form to edit a question so as to make an answer irrelevant like this.